# C++ 'surcharge' variable is not being set properly

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

I just can't seem to get the surcharge variable to equal 0 when the age is outside the range of 18-25.

The program runs fine when the input includes a surcharge but when the surcharge has to equal 0, it says it is not initialized.

My code is below.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int age, accidents, basic = 500, surcharge, program, total;
char safety;

cout << "Enter your age: " << endl;
cin >> age;

cout << "Enter # of accidents: " << endl;
cin >> accidents;

cout << "Did you attend a driver saftey program? y/n: ";
cin >> safety;

if (age < 18 || accidents >= 6)
{
    cout << "You are not eligible for insurance";
}
else

if (age >= 18 || age <= 25)
    surcharge = 100;
else
    surcharge == 0;


if (accidents == 1 && safety == 'n')
    program = 50;
else if (accidents == 2 && safety == 'n')
    program = 125;
else if (accidents == 3 && safety == 'n')
    program = 225;
else if (accidents == 4 && safety == 'n')
    program = 375;
else if (accidents == 5 && safety == 'n')
    program = 575;
// attended driver safety course
else if (accidents == 1 && safety == 'y')
    program = 35;
else if (accidents == 2 && safety == 'y')
    program = 100;
else if (accidents == 3 && safety == 'y')
    program = 200;
else if (accidents == 4 && safety == 'y')
    program = 325;
else if (accidents == 5 && safety == 'y')
    program = 500;
else
    program = 0;

total = basic + surcharge + program;

cout << "Your total is: " << total << endl;

getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand from this error message in particular?

Comment: `surcharge == 0` is a test not an assignment, you mean `else surcharge = 0;`. Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`), learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: I understand what the message is saying, I just want to know how to fix it so when the age is outside the bounds of 18-25, the surcharge will equal 0

Comment: @JacolbyHartson _"I just want to know how to fix it ..."_ Simply initialize it, may be in the line of it's declaration, at least **before** you're using it at any point.

Comment: @JacolbyHartson see my answer. You are improperly checking the age range between 18 and 25 making it appear as if your variable surcharge isn't being set properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 bugs near each other that I can see. You wrote:

```
if (age >= 18 || age <= 25)
    surcharge = 100;
else
    surcharge == 0;
```

Should be:

```
if (age >= 18 && age <= 25)
    surcharge = 100;
else
    surcharge = 0;
```

You need to check for `age >= 18` AND (`&&`) `age <= 25` not OR (`||`)

The other bug was that `surcharge == 0` should have been `surcharge = 0` (You want assignment not equality)

As well if you have no insurance you want to exit the program after displaying the error so you should consider a change where you return after printing the error message:

```
if (age < 18 || accidents >= 6)
{
    cout << "You are not eligible for insurance" << endl;
    return 1; // A value > 0 usually denotes an error occurred
}
```

Comment: Yes the '&&' worked and so did the return 1, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

At this point

```
if (age >= 18 || age <= 25)
    surcharge = 100;
else
    surcharge == 0;  // <--- here
```

I think you want to write

```
    surcharge = 0;
```

Comment: in place of the if statement? or where at?

Comment: @JacolbyHartson Line 4 of the quoted code uses `==`. It should use `=`. Do you understand the difference between those two operators?

Comment: I changed that and it still is not initialized, I didn't actually mean to put that in here, I was just trying different things out.

Comment: In that case, can you tell us exactly which variable the error says is not initialized? The == test as it is posted, would cause such an error, since you attempt to test an uninitialized variable against 0.

Comment: The variable that is not initialized is the surcharge variable

Comment: Also it should be `&&` rather than `||`

Comment: Yes @MattMcNabb that was the bug I identified in my solution as well. That is the reason the OP thinks that `surcharge` appears to not be initialized properly.

Comment: @JacolbyHartson after changing == to =, do you still get an 'uninitialized variable' error, or does the variable have the wrong value? In the latter case, others here have shown that a range check as you mean to do it, requires, in this case, a && operator, not a ||

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be initialized, simply initialize it. Change the following line

```
int age, accidents, basic = 500, surcharge, program, total;
```

to

```
int age, accidents, basic = 500, surcharge = 0, program, total;
```